# wordpress | Write a simple form plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want to write a plugin which is actually a form with multiple fields. I want just CRUD operations on that form. I can't use some other plugin to create the form using wordpress hooks. I have to write my own form plugin and this is my first experience in wordpress. How can I write this plugin?

Comment: What have you tried? I'm sure there's plenty of Wordpress plugin tutorials out there, Wordpress even supply their [own](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

Comment: Might be more appropriate to ask over at the [WordPress Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: As you expected there are some people who has googled for you.